# How to convert a columns 'date' in a glue context dynamic frame using mapping?

Tags: parquet, aws-glue

I have an input csv file with two columns: name and expirationdate.

In my Glue job I am opening the file into a dynamic frame from options and looks good, but when printing the schema all the columns are string.

So I want to convert the date into a date column and then save it as parquet.

I am creating a temporal dynamic frame with mapping as follows:

`myFrame = originalDynamicFrameFromOptions.apply_mapping([('name','string','name','string'),('expirationdate','date','expirationdate','date')])`

When I print the schema looks good, but when trying to save it as parquet I get the following error:

'Unsupported case of DataType: com.amazonasaws.services.glue.schema.types and DynamicNode:stringnode'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.